# Invalid credentials for reverse geocoding

Tags: here-api

Here is my call

```
https://reverse.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json
?apiKey=SWxxxxxxx_D6xxxxxxxxx_ahxxxxxxxxxxxx&prox=41.8842,-87.6388,250&maxresults=1&mode=retrieveAddresses
```

Here is my response

```
<ns2:Error xmlns:ns2="http://www.navteq.com/lbsp/Errors/1" type="PermissionError" subtype="InvalidCredentials">
    <Details>invalid credentials for ZZtoxxxxxxxxxx</Details>
</ns2:Error>
```

However, this call, with the same credentials, returns a valid payload.

```
https://geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/search/6.2/geocode.json?languages=en-US&maxresults=4&searchtext=12 Main St&country=USA&SWxxxxxxx_D6xxxxxxxxx_ahxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Please advise on how to correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a space between

> https....?

and

> apiKey

Getting rid of that space should resolve your issue.
https://reverse.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?apiKey={{RESTapiKey}}&prox=41.8842,-87.6388,250&mode=retrieveAddresses&maxresults=1

Comment: I copied the URL from https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder/dev_guide/topics/example-reverse-geocoding.html. It appears that when pasted, it's adding a hidden HTML character.